# Update values set in autocomplete dynamically created textbox

Tags: jquery-ui

I need ideas to handle the mouse click selection  and the hand written text in an autocomplete textbox to be saved through a controller in JQuery. 
Im clear with the saving part, the issue im facing isthat when I select (click) on any option in the autocomplete box, the onblur is called and it only takes the first word ive typed and tries saving it to the database.
Whereasif i comment out the select event in autocomplete and only handle onblur of the textbox, the handwritten value is saved and the clicked value from the autocomplete isnt saved.
Any ideas ?